# UITableView weird padding at the bottom of cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView in which I am displaying bunch of custom cells. The cell is configured to be 50 pixels in height:

[image]

I am retuning 50 in the heightForRow method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 50.f
}
```

But in the end, there's a weird 10-15ish pixel padding/spacing between each cell:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your custom cell's configuration code, I can only guess. The space you see is likely internal to the cell. Perhaps you've added a green subview, but it isn't sized to fit the cell. You probably need to set the subview to have a flexible height (or if you're using Auto Layout, pin the top and bottom to the parent).

Or maybe you have one cell per section and you're somehow creating a blank header or footer.

Comment: Cell doesn't have any subviews. I haven't implemented any delegate methods for headers.